# Python algorithm to search keys and values

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Part of an algorithm course I am taking is to use look through a dictionary of keys and values and continue to look for matching keys & values. For example if there is a matching key, use the value to look up the next key and continue down the rabbit hole. If a match if found more than once to prevent an infinite loop return False else it should return the last key found.

1. Look up a key called "bat", and find a value "pig" then continue
2. Look up a key called "pig", and find "cat" then continue
3. Look up a key called "cat", and find "dog" then continue
4. Look up a key called "dog", and find "ant" then continue
5. Look up a key called "ant", and find no associated value, and so it
   would return "ant"

This is the data:

```
d = {'bat': 'pig', 'pig': 'cat', 'cat': 'dog', 'dog': 'ant', 'cow': 'bee', 'bee': 'elk', 'elk': 'fly', 'ewe': 'cod', 'cod': 'hen', 'hog': 'fox', 'fox': 'jay', 'jay': 'doe', 'rat': 'ram', 'ram': 'rat'}
```

This is my function below where I am trying learn recursion...and understand why my function doesn't `return False` when a key saved to `MEMORY` has a value greater than 2.

```
def rabbit_hole(dictionry,key,MEMORY={}):
    
    #print(MEMORY)
    
    if key in MEMORY:
        MEMORY[key] += 1
        
    else:
        MEMORY[key] = 1
        

    for val in MEMORY.values():
        #print(val)

        if val == 2:
            return False # <--- why not working?

    for k,v in dictionry.items():
        if k == key:
            
            # recursive call
            rabbit_hole(dictionry,v,MEMORY)

    #print("return last added dict key")
    return list(MEMORY)[-1]
```

Any tips appreciated not a lot of wisdom here...if I run:

```
print(rabbit_hole(d, "bat"))
print(rabbit_hole(d, "ewe"))
print(rabbit_hole(d, "jay"))
print(rabbit_hole(d, "yak"))
print(rabbit_hole(d, "rat"))
```

The code above returns:

```
ant
hen
doe
yak
ram
```

But its supposed to return a `False` on `rat` like this:

```
ant
hen
doe
yak
False
```

Comment: `for k,v in dictionry.items(): if k == key: rabbit_hole(dictionry,v,MEMORY)` is a very inefficient way to do `if key in dictionry: rabbit_hole(dictionry, dictionry[key], MEMORY)`

Comment: Anyway, you're missing a `return` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, this point can help you:

- Your condition to break out of the recursive loop should normally
  come first, which is if the key is in MEMORY
- You need to return the value of the recursive call *thanks Abhinav*

In addition, some style/optimisation suggestions:

- If you want to keep track of what you have seen so far, you can use a
  `set` over a `dict`
- Then with a dictionary, you dont need to loop over the keys (that
  defeats the point of a dictionary). You can just see if a key is in
  the dictionary, and if it is, get the value.
- [Replace the default mutable argument](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) `dict` with None, and then set it as a dictionary (or set) if it is passed in as None. This is because if you re-run the function:

```
print(rabbit_hole(d, "bat"))
print(rabbit_hole(d, "bat"))
```

It will reuse the same dictionary/set which will then have preexisting keys, rather than creating a new dictionary

```
ant
False
```

I would suggest you try again with these points, but if not here is a solution:

> ```
>  def rabbit_hole(dictionary, key, seen=None):
>     if seen is None:
>         seen = set()
>
>     if key in seen:
>         return False
>
>     seen.add(key)
>
>     if key in dictionary:
>         return rabbit_hole(dictionary, dictionary[key], seen)
>     return key
> ```

Comment: Replacing the default mutable value by `None` and an `if` like you did in the solution is really good, but the OP probably won't know why you did it. I suggest adding an explanation for that.

Comment: Or linking to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Or linking to the tutorial from the official documentation, which has a warning against mutable default arguments: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is, you're not returning the value from the recursive call. As a result, the function returns the last value from the memory list.
This simple fix should return the correct value:

```py
    for k,v in dictionry.items():
        if k == key:
            # recursive call
            return rabbit_hole(dictionry,v,MEMORY)
```

Comment: ah thanks....the learning curve is high here....

Comment: Ill hit the green check box....still trying to soak in the theory of recursion....that I need the `return` ill probably finally get it after about 100 more practice problems : )